# C# помогите sqlite blob

Tags: c#, sqlite, blob

Как BLOB показать в консоли? У меня целый час выходит такой код `system.byte[]`.

[image: system.byte[]].

`reader[5].tostring` - это поле blob.

```
string record = null;

SQLiteDataReader reader;
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:\\data;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;");

connection.Open();
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM database", connection);
reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    record = reader[5].ToString();
    connection.Clone();
    Console.WriteLine(record);
    console.readkey();
}`
```

---

да блоб это скрытые данные .  я все кто пробовал но не че не выходит.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

вот код. а в базе я ничего не заносил. пока что я пробую на базу данных google chrome. Login Data.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {



        string record = null;

        SQLiteDataReader reader;


        SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:\\login data;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;");



        connection.Open();
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM logins", connection);
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();


        while (reader.Read())

        {

            byte[] bytes = (byte[])reader[5];





                foreach (byte b in bytes)
                  Console .WriteLine (Encoding.Default .GetString    ((byte[])reader[5]));
                Console.ReadKey();




            connection.Clone();


        }





    }
}
```

}

---

**в блоб хранится пароль , в зашифрованном виде**.
я все так сделал . но в места текста я получаю только символы. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В каком виде вы хотите получить блоб в консоли. Например, в базе лежит блоб из 32 байт от 0 до 31. вид 010203..0E0F10...1F подойдет?

Comment: но например этот подойдет.

Comment: Покажите код, как вы заносили данные в БД. И, ради всего святого, не надо скриншотов! Покажите код в виде текста.

Answer (score 2):

Консоль может выводить только текст. У массива байт метод ToString() не перегружен и поэтому возвращает имя типа. Массив байт сначала нужно декодировать. Если ваш блоб это текст то (только кодировку правильно выберите):

```
record = Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[])reader[5]);
```

или

```
record = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString((byte[])reader[5]);
```

Если блоб это сырые данные то:

```
record = Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])reader[5]);
```

или

```
record = BitConverter.ToString((byte[])reader[5]).Replace("-","");
```

Answer (score 2):

Выполните приведение возвращаемого значения к типу `byte[]`.

```
byte[] bytes = (byte[])reader[5];
```

После чего можно работать с полученным массивом байтов. Например, вывести шестнадцатеричные значения:

```
foreach (byte b in bytes)
    Console.Write(b.ToString("X") + " ");
Console.WriteLine();
```

Или строку по основанию 64:

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));
```